Meromorphic function $g$ sharing value(s) with its derivative $g'$ counting multiplicity (CM). What does it mean?
I am working on some of the fundamental results of functions sharing values with their derivatives as an application of Nevanlinna Theory. There are many results for meromorphic functions sharing values CM with their derivate, but I don't really understand, what this means. I have the following definition (Jank & Volkmann, S.79):
Two meromorphic functions $w_1$ and $w_2$ share a value $a\in\hat{\mathbb{C}}$, if
\begin{align*}
\{z \vert w_1(z)=a\}=\{z \vert w_2(z)=a\}=A.
\end{align*}
They share the value $a$ with multiplicity (CM), if for every $z_0$ the $a$-points of $w_1$ and $w_2$ have the same multiplicity.
What I know as the multiplicity of a $\textbf{zero}$ $z_0$ of a function $w$ is the minimal $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $w^{(1)}(z_0)=0, \dots,w^{(k-1)}(z_0)=0, w^{(k)}(z_0)\neq 0$. But what is the multiplicity for a point $a\in\hat{\mathbb{C}}\setminus\{0\}$?
If we transmit this definition roughly to a point $a\in\hat{\mathbb{C}}\setminus\{0\}$ this $\textbf{could}$ mean that the multiplicity of an $a$-point $z_0$ is the minimal $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $w^{(1)}(z_0)=a, \dots,w^{(k-1)}(z_0)=a, w^{(k)}(z_0)\neq a$.
When taking the above definition, I don't understand how a (meromorphic) function $g$ can share a value $a$ with its derivate $g'$ CM, because the multiplicity of an $a$-point of $g'$ should always be one less than for $g$ (except the case that they both omit the value $a$).
In one paper I've read that two functions $w_1$ and $w_2$ share the value $a\in\mathbb{C}$ CM if $w_1-a$ and $w_2-a$ have the same zeros with the same multiplicities, which, for $g$ and $g'$, confuses me the same way.
Where is my mistake?
Example for two functions sharing a value CM:

References:
Jank & Volkmann (1985): Einführung in die Theorie der ganzen und meromorphen Funktionen mit Anwendungen auf Differentialgleichungen, Basel: Springer Verlag

Can you give an example of one such result mentioned (about functions that share values with its derivative)

I added one to the post

so you get your answer - if (nontrivial) $f,f'$ share a value, then it must be nonzero and all preimages there have simple multiplicity  - the example you added shows that $f(w)=1$ iff $f'(w)=1$ and since if $w$ would be a root of order $2$ of $f-1$ then $f'(w)=0$ which is not possible; for example $f(z)=1+z+z^2$ satisfies $f(0)=f'(0)=1$ though of course the equation $f(z)-1=0$ has more solutions in this case so you need a complicated example like the above for a shared value and the theorem mentioned shows that is the best one can do unless $f'=f$

@Conrad thanks for your answer. You say that if $f$ and $f'$ share a value it must be nonzero, because of ID theorem? you also say that all preimages there have simple multipl., but what do you mean by multipl. in this context? Lets say $f-a=0\Leftrightarrow f'-a=0$ and let $z_0$ be such an a-point of $f$, i.e. $f(z_0)-a=0$. Then $z_0$ is a simple a-point, because it is a simple zero of $f-a$ since $(f-a)′(_0)=f'(_0)=a\neq 0$. Then, because $f$ and $f'$ share the value $a\neq 0$ CM, the multiplicity of $z_0$ for $f'$ is also 1. Is this what you mean by the multiplicity of $z_0$ for $f$?

Yes correct - I think you got it so $f,f'$ sharing values is possible but unless $f=f'$ can happen only for one value and there are the constraints mentioned (value nonzero, each solution for the value simple)

@Conrad thank you!

Happy to be of help
